# How to handle WebClient response to display error message to user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a MVC Web App which is calling a Web API. In my Create (POST) method, a user will enter email addresses of some users in the database. I have a check to enter the email only if the email does not already exist in the database or not. If it already exists, I want to be able to show an error message to the user "Email already exists".

I don't know how to handle the response to display an error message to the user when it fails to create an approveduser? I am trying with a `try-catch` case, but it is not working. I have `ViewBag.Message = error` which I am trying to display in my Index View when it fails. But nothing is displaying. When I debug, it doesn't even go to the `catch` when the email exists in the database, it just takes me to the Index view.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Email,FirstName,LastName")] ApprovedUsers approvedUsers)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            token = Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("access_token");
            client.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues(apiUrl, "POST", new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "Email", approvedUsers.Email },
                { "FirstName",approvedUsers.FirstName },
                { "LastName",approvedUsers.LastName }
            });

            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { error = "Email exists" });
    }
}
```

**Index** Action

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string error)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = error;
```

This is the **API** method being called.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostApprovedUsers(ApprovedUsers approvedUsers)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

if (!db.ApprovedUsers.Any(u => u.Email == approvedUsers.Email))
{
    db.ApprovedUsers.Add(approvedUsers);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = approvedUsers.Email }, approvedUsers);
```

Comment: Just wondering what does Index action look like?

Comment: I have added a portion of code from my Index ViewResult in my post. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Put breakpoint on entry to Index.  Look for the content you are trying to pass in.  You are attempting to pass an object to a method that doesn't take one.  Instead it takes these: string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string error.  If you have an error string parameter for example you could pass that in.  But in general with that many parameters it's better to create a model and pass that in insted.

Comment: The error string is in the catch of the Create method. It was displaying the message in the Index page when I didn't use the try & catch. Like when an user was created, the View did show the error string. I have that many parameters because I am doing paging, search-filter, and sorting for the Index page table.

Comment: Your `PostApprovedUsers` doesn't return an error if the user exists, you need to return some sort of error status code (similar to `BadRequest`) for it to hit that `catch` block, otherwise it sees the result as being a non-error result and redirects to your index action as expected.

Comment: That was just what I finally figure like few minutes ago. Took me to 2 days to notice this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my API that was causing the issue. Even when it failed to create the duplicate email, it never went to the `catch` because I didn't have a bad request return if the email did exist in the database.

Changed my API to this and then it was working.

```
if (db.ApprovedUsers.Any(u => u.Email == approvedUsers.Email))
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Email exists already");
}
else
{
    db.ApprovedUsers.Add(approvedUsers);
}
   try
   {
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (DbUpdateException e)
   {
      if (ApprovedUsersExists(approvedUsers.Id))
       {
          return Conflict();
       }
       throw e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Email,FirstName,LastName")] ApprovedUsers approvedUsers)
{ 
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            token = Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("access_token");
            client.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues(apiUrl, "POST", new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "Email", approvedUsers.Email },
                { "FirstName",approvedUsers.FirstName },
                { "LastName",approvedUsers.LastName }
            });

            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);            
        }
    }
    catch
    {
       TempData["Error"] = "Email Exists";});
    }

  RedirectToAction("Index");

 }

public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string error)
  {
      ViewBag.Message = TempData["Error"].ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I never used ViewBag, rather Strongly Type models which contain error information.  If you want to use view bag, I've corrected example